# Execute two UPDATEs on complementary data at once in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I have the following table that I need to update:

```
USER:

| ID | ACTIVE | REF_COL | COL_2 | COL_3 |
|----|--------|---------|-------|-------|
| 1  |    1   |  value  | value | value |
| 2  |    0   |  value  | value | value |
| 3  |    1   |  value  | value | value |
```

I execute the following two `UPDATE` statements separately:

1. Statement-1

   ```
   UPDATE
       USER
   SET
       ACTIVE = 1
   WHERE
       REF_COL IN (
           -- Subquery that generates a list of values
       )
   ```
2. Statement-2

   ```
   UPDATE
       USER
   SET
       ACTIVE = 0
   WHERE
       REF_COL NOT IN (
           -- Subquery that generates a list of values
       )
   ```

The Subquery that generates a list of values is the same for both of the `UPDATE` queries.

Is there any way which will help me to execute the query at once, like `MERGE`?

The following query using `MERGE` statement is invalid:

```
MERGE INTO USER U
USING (
    -- Subquery that generates a list of values
) T
ON (U.REF_COL = T.VALUE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET U.ACTIVE = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET U.ACTIVE = 0
```

Since the `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN` clause expects to have an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: please show the subquery!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh, the question I asked to demonstrate the problem in a simple manner. In the actual case, there are lots of tables associated and I cannot expose their name.

Comment: could the ref_col column in the user table contain null values? If so, should those rows be updated too, or ignored?

Comment: @Boneist, no the `REF_COL` is set to be non-null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `merge` version with example. You have to place logic in *source* part:

```
merge into users tgt
using (
  select u.ref_col, nvl2(s.ref_col, 1, 0) active
    from users u 
    left join subquery s on u.ref_col = s.ref_col ) src
on (tgt.ref_col = src.ref_col)
when matched then update set active = src.active;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7ccd3b8e9cd8e83027730bf066567802)</sup>**

Comment: Hi, could you please check the answer I have given. Also, your idea worked like a charm, hence I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CASE` in `SET`

```
UPDATE
    USER U
SET
    U.ACTIVE = (CASE WHEN U.REF_COL IN (<subquery>) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b1b8887378bf1b5565e74457992fdcf8)

Comment: I'm suspecting the subquery would get evaluated for every row of the `USER`.

Comment: @TapasBose If the subquery returns a static list of values, then it will be cached, meaning it will only be run once.

Comment: @TapasBose definitely not in Oracle

Comment: Avoiding `merge` is definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using the idea provided by **Ponder Stibbons** in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55827305/576758), I have created the following query; the extra logic that I have added is to filter only those rows for which the `ACTIVE` value needs to be updated:

```
MERGE INTO USER U
USING (
    SELECT
        TGT.ID,
        SRC.ACTIVE
    FROM
        USER TGT
        JOIN (
            SELECT
                U.REF_COL,
                NVL2(T.REF_COL, 1, 0) AS ACTIVE
            FROM
                USER U
                LEFT JOIN (
                    -- Subquery that generates a list of values
                ) T ON T.REF_COL = U.REF_COL            
        ) SRC ON TGT.REF_COL = SRC.REF_COL
    WHERE
        TGT.ACTIVE != SRC.ACTIVE
) F
ON (U.ID = F.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        U.ACTIVE = F.ACTIVE
```

Comment: Looks OK. If I understand correctly line `WHERE TGT.ACTIVE != SRC.ACTIVE` is because you want to update only rows that differs. If column `USER.ACTIVE` does not / cannot contains nulls it should work fine.

Comment: Exactly. The `ACTIVE` is non-nullable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

pesudocode for merge:

```
MERGE into <target table>

    USING
        <souce table/view/result of subquery>
    ON
        <match condition>
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        <update clause>
        <delete clause>
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        <insert clause>
```

oracle docs goes like:
*The merge_insert_clause specifies values to insert into the column of the target table if the condition of the ON clause is false. If the insert clause is executed, then all **insert triggers** defined on the target table are activated. If you omit the column list after the INSERT keyword, then the number of columns in the target table must match the number of values in the VALUES clause.*
 you cant use merge or two update one for match and other for unmatch.

**you would have to create a procedure instead.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE all_updates_in_user
IS
   cursor c1 is<<query that generates a list of values>>
BEGIN

  FOR rec in c1
   LOOP

   UPDATE
    USER
SET
    ACTIVE = 1
WHERE
    REF_COL IN rec.columnname;

   UPDATE
    USER
SET
    ACTIVE = 0
WHERE
    REF_COL  NOT IN rec.columnname;  
 END LOOP;
END;
```